# AngularJS same controller in non nested divs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have got two separate divs as shown in the code below. What I am trying to do is update the Controller from first div and then detect the changes in the second div using the same controller. When I press the button, 'i am here' gets printed on the console but the data in 2nd div won't update. It should change to "clicked".

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Divs below should not be nested</h1>

    <div id="notNested1" ng-controller="Controller1">
        <button ng-click="buttonClick()">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="notNested2" ng-controller="Controller1">
        <p>{{paragraph}}</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        function Controller1($scope) {

            $scope.paragraph = 'initial';

            $scope.buttonClick = function () {
                console.log('i am here');
                $scope.paragraph = "clicked";
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this problem? Also what is the problem here? Is it because the $scope is different for both divs?

Thanks

Comment: common misconception when learning to use angular is that instances of controller will be the same, they aren't. Each element will have it's own instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably share the data using a service/factory.

You could also create a parent controller with the data there, and reference it from the child controllers, but a shared service seems better.

Yes you have 2 separate scopes, so they do not interact with each other.

Comment: That means I should have two separate controllers. First controller broadcasts the event and second controller catches the event and then update the scope? My other question is, is there a way to do it with single controller?

Comment: I have done it using two separate controllers, and by firing broadcast event. I am also maintaining a separate shared factory, because at times I need to check if the data is selected in first controller.